# For the Swarmkeeper ranger's Gathered Swarm feature, does being moved by the swarm provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, movement, opportunity-attack, ranger

The [Swarmkeeper ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Swarmkeeper) from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 60) has the [Gathered Swarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#GatheredSwarm-2991401) feature, which provides the following benefit:

> Once on each of your turns, you can cause the swarm to assist you in
> one of the following ways, immediately after you hit a creature with
> an attack:
>
> - [...]
> - You are moved by the swarm 5 feet horizontally in a direction of your choice.

If you use this feature to leave the reach of a creature, does this movement provoke an opportunity attack?

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted; this is a perfectly-reasonable question. On the off-chance that it is the explanation for the voting, may I remind everyone that self-answered questions are not only allowed, but **encouraged**, on this site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No, it doesn't

The rules for [opportunity attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) state the following (emphasis mine):

> You don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or **when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction.**

Gathered Swarm clearly states that the **swarm** moves you. Furthermore, this movement does not use your action (as it is a rider effect on an attack), and it doesn't use your own movement. Therefore, you do not provoke an opportunity attack.